# TAB key navigation for sap.m.Table

Tags: sapui5

I have some data input fields inside a `sap.m.table`. Wanted to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to navigate to the input fields but it doesn't work. 
It seems the SAP application interface hasn't implemented this feature.
I tried with some custom function and not working.

Any solution or alternative for this feature?

Answer (score 2):

SAP itself now come up with the solution. Navigation with the TAB key is available form SAPUI5 version 1.44.

SAP NOTE 2387996 - SAPUI5 unable to use Tab to move to next field.
We have to press F2 key to activate this.

Comment: great thanks. additionally after your post I found out, that with this.byId("tablename").setKeyboardMode(sap.m.ListKeyboardMode.Edit); a manually pressing of F2 is not needed anymore

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer necessary to use a custom solution for this. As of SAPUI5 version 1.38.0 sap.m.table has a property called 'keyboardMode' that can be set to 'Edit' which will change the tab behaviour to navigate focus through all editable fields in the table.

> This mode is suitable if the number of items is limited and if there
>   are editable fields within the item.
>
> While the last/first interactive element within an item has the focus,
>   pressing tab/shift+tab moves the focus to the next/previous element in
>   the tab chain after/before the item .

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListKeyboardMode

Answer (score -1):

Attach browser event

```
new sap.m.Input({
    value:"{first}"
}).attachBrowserEvent("keydown",function(oEvent){
    if(oEvent.key == 'Tab'){
        alert(this);//this reference to input control
        //Your logic here
    }
})
```

[Sample JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/fusazujino/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it's not moving to the next row.

Comment: @Anoop if you haven't implemented anything at the part where the answer says "//Your logic here", it's to be expected that the cursor is not moving on tab key.